# LinkButton.Text coming undefined in js

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to configure a hyperlink to close/open its related div in asp.net. Basically, when a user clicks the sign X, the panel should be closed and the sign + should be appeared. When + is clicked, the panel should be showed again. I could not manage this and I believe my main problem is "document.getElementById('<%= lb_closePanel.ClientID %>').value" is coming as undefined. Here is the code until now. I appreciate for your helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
<div class="appheader">
    <h1 class="appheaderContent">Search for Client</h1>
    <div id="checkBox"></div>
        <div id="closePanel"><h2 id="lblClosePanel">Close Panel</h2>
            <div id="xButton">
                <asp:LinkButton onclientclick="CloseOpenPanel('Search')" runat="server" Text="X" style="text-decoration:none; color:white" ID="lb_closePanel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="app" id="Search">
...
<div>
...
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseOpenPanel(obj) {      
        alert(document.getElementById('<%= lb_closePanel.ClientID %>').value); //here it comes undefined!!!!
        if (document.getElementById('<%= lb_closePanel.ClientID %>').value == 'X') {
            document.getElementById(obj).Visible = false;
            lb_closePanel.Text = '+';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(obj).Visible = true;
            lb_closePanel.Text = 'X';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK, just instead of the property `value` use `innerHTML`

```
 alert(document.getElementById('<%= lb_closePanel.ClientID %>').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .value, try using .innerHTML instead to get the text inside of your link button (rendered as an a tag)